# Thymeleaf views not found with springboot

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to follow this tutorial for adding thymeleaf to a springboot app but I can't seem to get it to work.
Tutorial:  http://spr.com/part-2-adding-views-using-thymeleaf-and-jsp-if-you-want/

I was able to get springboot to work fine when I started the app using @RestController in LoginController but when I changed @RestController to @Controller I'm getting an error page saying:

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

I set a breakpoint in the controller and confirmed that it is hitting the index method in LoginController.  I feel like this has to do with how I've added Thymeleaf since I haven't done much else to the application but everything I've tried so far results in the same error page.

my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
baseName = 'GazeFest'
version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:3.0.0.RELEASE")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '3.0'
}
```

my Application.java

package gazefest;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

}
```

my LoginController.java

```
package gazefest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "HELLO!");
    return "index";
}

}
```

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>HELLO</title>
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="${message}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

my file structure
[image: fileStructure]

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should be using the **thymeleaf-spring4** dependency, but you should be using the Spring boot starter for Thymeleaf.

For Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For Gradle:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
```

I suggest using the [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/) to set up your project. This allows you to select any Spring boot starter and add it to your Gradle/Maven descriptor so you won't make any mistakes by picking a dependency.

Comment: I tried starting a new project using Spring Initializr with the same LoginController.java from above but I'm running into the same error page.

Comment: Is there some place I need to specify where my html files are located?  I thought the resources/templates folder I have index.html in currently is supposed to be the default but its like it can't find them

Comment: The **src/main/resources/templates** folder (which should be generated by the Spring Initialzr) should be the right folder yes.

Comment: Adding compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf") to gradle config fixed my problem.
This is a very tricky thing, because initially I saw a 404 page and no error logs in console. Under such conditions it's not obvious at all that the issue is actually with missing thymeleaf dependency.